# Find first 3 occurences and order them pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given the following data frame, I want to get the first 3 occurrences of all Teachers based on the created column with an additional column to indicate the appearance.

I've tried the groupby but I don't know how to keep the first 3 instances.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
                     {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,],
                     'Section': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B',
                                 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                     'Teacher': ['Kakashi', 'Kakashi', 'Iruka',
                                 'Kakashi', 'Kakashi', 'Kakashi',
                                 'Iruka', 'Iruka', 'Guy'],
                     'created': [datetime(2022,7,11), datetime(2022, 7, 12), datetime(2022, 7, 13), 
                                 datetime(2022, 7, 14), datetime(2022, 7, 15), datetime(2022, 7, 16), 
                                 datetime(2022, 7, 17), datetime(2022, 7, 18), datetime(2022, 7, 19), ]})
```

ex. output

```
_id Section Teacher created               appearance_order
1.  A       Kakashi datetime(2022,7,11).  1
2.  A       Kakashi datetime(2022, 7, 12) 2
4.  A       Kakashi datetime(2022, 7, 14) 3
3.  B       Iruka   datetime(2022, 7, 13) 1
7.  C.      Iruka.  datetime(2022, 7, 17) 2 
8.  C.      Iruka.  datetime(2022, 7, 18) 3
9.  C.      Guy.    datetime(2022, 7, 19) 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) of sorted values and then filter lower values like `4`:

```
data = data.sort_values(['Teacher','created'], ignore_index=True)

data['appearance_order'] = data.groupby('Teacher').cumcount().add(1)
df = data[data['appearance_order'].lt(4)]
print (df)
   id Section  Teacher    created  appearance_order
0   9       C      Guy 2022-07-19                 1
1   3       A    Iruka 2022-07-13                 1
2   7       C    Iruka 2022-07-17                 2
3   8       C    Iruka 2022-07-18                 3
4   1       A  Kakashi 2022-07-11                 1
5   2       A  Kakashi 2022-07-12                 2
6   4       B  Kakashi 2022-07-14                 3
```